# Colored Tiles in SSRS / Mobile Reports

Tags: sql-server, dashboard, ssrs-2016

i want a really simple report:

A square tile and it should display a number for values > 0.
The color of the tile should be managed no matter what numeric value is being displayed.

I tried to do it with mobile reports in sql server 2016 but there i can only color a tile dependent of the number that will be displayed.

Thing is i have two different logics. one for color one for the number.

You know of any built-in functionality of SSRS 2016 that can do that?

Answer (score 0):

With a regular table (or a matrix) you can display the value with one field or expression and set the **BackGroundColor** property with another field or expression as the text box's color.

This would let you display one value in the text box while basing the color on a different field

[image]

Comment: sorry to say but i am really looking for square tiles and not an old school paginated report

Comment: @tuxmania - what's the difference between a square tile and a text box?

Comment: i just want no table designed report